# Receiving the serializeArray data from AJAX to processing php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

```
$('#submit').click(function()
{
var data = JSON.stringify($("#players_form").serializeArray());
alert(data);
$.ajax({ // Send the credential values to another checker.php using Ajax in POST menthod
        type : 'POST',
        data : data,
        url  : 'process.php',
        success: function(responseText)
       {
            if(responseText == 1)
            {
            alert("Sucess");
            }
        }
```

In this code I have passed the form values to process.php but I could not be able to receive the posted values in process.php , could any one suggest me to recieve the array values in process.php

```
<form id="players_form"  >
<input type=" text" name="main_name[]" value="">
<input type=" text" name="main_name[]" value="">
<input type=" text" name="main_name[]" value="">
<input type=" text" name="main_name[]" value="">
<input type=" text" name="main_name[]" value="">
<input type=" text" name="sub_name[]" value="">
<input type=" text" name="sub_name[]" value="">
<input type=" text" name="sub_name[]" value="">
<input type=" text" name="sub_name[]" value="">
<input type=" text" name="sub_name[]" value="">
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use serializeArray method in two different way.
`var data = JSON.stringify($("form").serializeArray());`
or

`var data = JSON.stringify($(":input").serializeArray());`

Comment: I would like to receive in PHP page

Comment: i understand your problem.you sent the wrong data. Apparently, Object convert to JSON function in jQuery so either  use http://api.jquery.com/serialize/   instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ajax script i make sure it works.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit').click(function() {
    var post_data = $("#players_form").serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: post_data,
      url: 'process.php',
      success: function(responseText) {
        console.log(responseText);
        if (responseText == 1) {
          alert("Sucess");
        }
      }
    })
  })
});
```

On **process.php** get the value like this

```
$main_name = $_POST['main_name'];
$sub_name = $_POST['sub_name'];
$main_name_version = implode(',', $main_name);
$sub_name_version = implode(',', $sub_name);
echo $main_name_version;
echo $sub_name_version;
```

Comment: It just retuns as array in process.php not the values

Comment: ArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArray

Answer (score 0):

replace data by,

```
 var data = $("#players_form").serializeArray();
```

make your request as,

```
dataType : 'JSON',
data : {players:data},
```

and  process data in server like below,

```
$player = $_POST['players'];
```